# A chessboard divided into four quadrants

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

Consider the following chessboard:

[image]

---

Divide it into four quadrants as shown:

[image]

---

- First quadrant is renamed as the Rook's quadrant.
- Second quadrant is renamed as the Bishop's quadrant.
- Third quadrant is renamed as the Knight's quadrant.
- Fourth quadrant is renamed as the Queen's quadrant.

---

***Your task is to fill out the empty Queen's quadrant by figuring out the logic used to fill other quadrants.***

---

Rook's quadrant

[image]

---

Bishop's quadrant

[image]

---

Knight's quadrant

[image]

---

Queen's quadrant

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queen's quadrant might be :

> ($3$,$\sqrt(18)$)  | ($5$,$3$)  |  ($5$,$3$)  |  ($3$,$\sqrt(18)$)
>
>  ($5$,$3$) | ($8$,$\sqrt(8)$) | ($8$,$\sqrt(8)$) | ($5$,$3$)
>
>  ($5$,$3$) | ($8$,$\sqrt(8)$) | ($8$,$\sqrt(8)$) | ($5$,$3$)
>
>  ($3$,$\sqrt(18)$)  |  ($5$,$3$)  |  ($5$,$3$)  |  ($3$,$\sqrt(18)$)

Explanation:

In each square, the first number is

> The number of directions available for the quadrant piece (R,B,N,Q) to move and remain in its quadrant.

And the second number is

> The distance that piece would travel to play its longest available move within its quadrant.

For example :

> A bishop on b8 can move in **2** directions (South-West or South-East) to stay in its quadrant. The longest move it can do (to d6) is **$\sqrt(8)$** squares long.
>  That's why ($2$,$\sqrt(8)$) is written in square b8.

This assumes :

> That you move your knight the way we teach it to beginners (two squares one way, then turn 90°, then one square, totalling three squares) and not directly to its destination (its score would then be $\sqrt(5)$ and not $3$)